# Button is not Taking Given Height and Width in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, xcode, button, swiftui, swiftui-button

I am new to **swiftui**. I am making a login screen in which I have to use log in with **apple and gmail** buttons. I am using a custom view to design the button. Here is the code for that custom button view:

```
struct CustomSocialButton: View {
    
    var ImgName: String
    
    var body: some View {
        
        
        Button(action: {
                  print("button pressed")

                }) {
                    Image(ImgName)
                    .renderingMode(.original)
                }
        
    }
}

struct CustomSocialButton_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        CustomSocialButton(ImgName: ImageName.appleSignin.rawValue)
    }
}
```

I am saving the image names to my constant file.

The problem is when I use it to my actual **login view** and setting its *width* and *height*. It is not taking that height and width. Here is the code for the buttons:

```
HStack(spacing: 10) {
                   
          CustomSocialButton(ImgName: ImageName.appleSignin.rawValue)
                .frame(width: 48, height: 48)
                   
          CustomSocialButton(ImgName: ImageName.googleSignin.rawValue)
                .frame(width: 48, height: 48)

       }
```

This is the screenshot of my login View: [image: login view]

Does anyone knows what I am doing wrong?

Comment: just add the  .resizable() under the Image() so that it can take the given height and width.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make image resizable, like

```
Image(ImgName)
   .renderingMode(.original)
   .resizable()               // << here !!
```

also might want to add `.aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)`

Answer (score 0):

You can work with
Spacer() oder Divider().

Divider will show some horizontally / vertically lines, I dont think that this is your need, so try Spacer().

What does **Spacer()** do? Spacer is a flexible space that expands with your view. It will "cut down" your horizontally (but also vertically) HStack (VStack) in layout parts. If you like to center a Text you can do it by using

```
HStack{
    Spacer()
    Text("Hi there");
    Spacer()
}
```

To resolve your problem, try something like this:

```
HStack(spacing: 10) {

    CustomSocialButton(ImgName: ImageName.appleSignin.rawValue)
                .frame(width: 48, height: 48)
    Spacer()
    
    CustomSocialButton(ImgName: ImageName.googleSignin.rawValue)
                .frame(width: 48, height: 48)

}
```

Comment: you can also do Spacer()CustomSocialButton() Spacer() CustomSocialButton() Spacer()....